# how to update npm version in Ubuntu (with permission)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, permissions

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and install node + npm. I know that I can't run npm command without `sudo`. Then I change my directory and give it permission that provide from this link https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions .
But when I try to run `npm install npm@latest -g`, npm will update the user-permission-given npm version, so when I run `npm -v` it will actually show me the version of root-permission npm not the user-permission-given npm. I want to know if I can change my npm global path to the permission given npm or there's another solution?

nb: I try to run root-permission npm (I delete user-permission npm folder from PATH) to install latest npm version, but it install latest npm with root-permission to my user-permission npm directory, which is give me more problem.

Comment: I don't know if it will solve your problem, but maybe NVM (Node Version Manager) will do the trick?  https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-nvm-node-version-manager-for-node-js-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

Comment: thanks for give me some advice.. but what I asked for is actually about the npm. I need to change root-permission npm folder to my user-permission npm folder.. but once again, thanks :) @theGleep

Comment: version of node and npm are paired up and typically installed together ... updating node will automatically give you its matching latest npm ... I have never encountered a need to update either separately ... if you used sudo to install node then you will have to issue sudo for npm commands however if you avoided using sudo during node install then no sudo is needed for your npm commands

Comment: see details at https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version/959382#959382